# Como estabelecer uma quantidade mínima e máxima de um valor requerido por um input numa requisição em JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um campo chamado `Quantidade` que deve ser inserido a quantidade de produtos para venda. Meu formulário possui uma requisição de dados que retorna o valor e a quantidade de produtos em estoque, esse campo `Quantidade` retorna essa quantidade de estoque de produtos por causa do `id="quantidade"`, então já recebe um valor.

Só que o campo `Quantidade` eu queria que tivesse um **limite mínimo e máximo para a quantidade inserida utilizando `min` e `max` dentro desse `<input>`, colocando um código PHP dentro do `max` para definir a quantidade máxima digitada (o `min` pode ser zero)**.

Exemplo: Se o campo `Quantidade` recebe um valor de 30 produtos por causa da requisição de dados, esse campo deve permitir uma inserção de no mínimo `0` até no máximo `30`, deixando o campo mais intuitivo.

Código JS que faz a requisição do valor no campo `Quantidade`

```
var retornoJson = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
document.querySelector("#quantidade").value = retornoJson[0].quantidade;
```

Código HTML:

```
<p> Quantidade: <input type="number" name="quantidade" id="quantidade" required=""> </p>
```

Comment: Existe, de fato, o tipo `type="int"` do `<input>` no HTML?

Comment: Sim, esse trecho de código ```<p> Quantidade </p>``` que eu postei, queria que ele fosse mais intuitivo no valor que ele recebe pra definir a quantidade digitada máxima permitida.

Comment: ```type="int"´´´ o ```<input>``` já possui, mas o usuário ele não sabe o valor mínimo é máximo para digitar nesse ```<input>```, só retorna a quantidade de estoque de uma requisição de dados (ex: 30) queria que impedisse valores acima do permitido.

Comment: concordo com o@Woss, não conheço type=int, seria um type=number ai certo?  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#atributos A questão é que `int` não é um tipo válido para o `<input>`; para valores numéricos deve-se usar `number`.

Comment: Não existe esse type="int" não, nós temos 21 tipos e nenhum deles é int. Tem o tipo number, mas quem aceita max e min é o tipo range

Answer (score 6):

Você não precisa do PHP para isso. Se você já faz a requisição para obter o valor, basta definí-lo com JavaScript mesmo:

```js
const quantidade = document.getElementById("quantidade");

quantidade.min = 0
quantidade.max = 5;
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
Quantidade: <input type="number" id="quantidade">
```

Perceba que mesmo que o usuário consiga inserir um valor maior que o máximo definido, o campo passa a ser inválido de acordo com a API de validação do JavaScript, que pode ser comprovado pelo CSS adicionado, que faz com que o campo fique vermelho.

Outro campo legal que pode ser utilizado é o tipo `range`:

```html
Quantidade: <input type="range" id="quantidade" min=0 max=5>
```

Comment: "min" e "max" tbm podem ser adicionados na tag input type=number, sem precisar de javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim, mas ele recebe o valor de `max` via requisição a uma API no JS; não é fixo.

Comment: @Woss como impedir a alteração manual do primeiro código que usa JS? Meu campo ```Quantidade``` possui uma máscara em JS que impede quantidade acima de número de 4 dígitos.

Comment: O que seria "alteração manual"?

Comment: eu clicar sobre o campo e digitar um valor sem usar as setas do campo?

Comment: Tem como eu mudar o ```quantidade.max = 5;``` pra algo que retorne o valor de ```id="quantidade"````?

Comment: E por que impediria de o usuário fazer isso? Se ele quisesse a quantidade 10, teria que clicar 10x? Parece-me inviável.